# Restringindo Acesso a Pagina php com Porta

Tags: php, apache

Estou fazendo um ambiente de login e gostaria que está página atendesse somente a uma porta de acesso préviamente configurada como "8080". Estou utilizando um servidor apache e ele será instalado por mim na máquina Linux.

Isso iria inteferir em outro site se mantido no mesmo servidor apache? Sem relação nenhuma com esse sistema de login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primeira coisa é ter certeza que seu servidor web está configurado para atender na porta que você deseja ter o *login*.

Como você comentou que usa Apache, a configuração relevante está aqui:

> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/bind.html

Basicamente, para atender em portas diferentes, você pode ajustar o `listen`:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080
```

Ou se a aplicação atender IPs diferentes e portas diferentes:

```
Listen 192.0.2.1:80
Listen 192.0.2.5:8080
```

Lembrando que se a aplicação de uma porta for diferente da outra, você pode configurar `virtualhosts` (o listen tem que estar aberto para todas as portas que for usar):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/caminho_para_o_site
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot /www/caminho_para_o_painel
</VirtualHost>
```

> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Caso não queira complicar, e o painel vá ficar hospedado junto do site principal, você pode usar a informação em `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']` para saber se a porta usada é a correta:

Veja um exemplo simplificado:

```
<?php
   if( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 8080 ) {
       echo '<h1>Porta n&atilde;o autorizada</h1>';
       // faz o que quiser aqui, no caso da porta estar errada
       // pode simular um 404, ou redirecionar pra onde achar melhor

       die(); // Importantissimo garantir que o script termine aqui
   }

   ... aqui continua sua página ...
```

Agora, se configurar esta parte do site para atender apenas na 8080, o próprio teste é desnecessário. Você precisa analisar dentro da sua situação concreta para determinar o melhor jeito.

Comment: Acredito que seria muito mais segura essa página atender somente em determinada porta, poderia me explicar mesmo a pergunta tendo sido mal formulada? Eu achava que isso era feito via PHP.

Comment: @AleChaito eu até teria explicado, mas como depende do servidor de páginas que vc usa e da hospedagem, eu não saberia o que acrescentar sem ter mais detalhes. Por exemplo, que servidor é? Apache, IIS, nginx, ou o que? Cada um se configura de um jeito. E isso se vc tiver acesso às configurações, senão tem que pedir pro suporte da empresa de hospedagem. Se quiser, como só tem a minha resposta ainda, clique em "editar" na pergunta e acrescente estes detalhes, que eu vejo se está no meu alcance completar a resposta.

Comment: @AleChaito dei uma melhorada na resposta, veja se ajuda.

Comment: Ajudou muito obrigado era disto mesmo que estava querendo saber.